# How to show $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty v_i a_{ij})^2$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assuming
\begin{align}
&\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty v_i^2 <\infty  \\
&\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty  a_{ij}^2 <\infty    ~~~~~~\forall i\ge 1  \\
&\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty  a_{ij}^2 <\infty    ~~~~~~\forall j\ge 1 
\end{align}
then how to show
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty v_i a_{ij})^2
$$
is convergent?    I can get the convergence of
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty v_i a_{ij}~~~~~~\forall j\ge 1
$$

But, I still  suspect it is not right, although I   fail to find counter-example after spending an afternoon.  Therefore, I asked here.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $a_{ij}=j$ if $i =j$ and $0$ is $i \neq j$. Let $v_j=\frac 1  j$ . Then $\sum_i v_ia_{ij}=1$ and $\sum_j (\sum_i v_ia_{ij})^{2}=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I really feel bad, even though I had a hunch it was wrong.  Thanks again.